# in Meteor, how do i update a property on only one instance of a template?

Tags: meteor

If I have an {{# each}} binding in Meteor, and I want to update a property on only one instance of the template inside the #each.  How would I do that?  I've tried setting a value on the "template" object inside the events map, but that doesn't seem to be reactive.  I've also tried binding to a Session property, but that will cause every instance to update instead of just the one I want...

for example:

```
{{#each dates}}
    {{> dateTemplate}}
{{/each}}

<template name="dateTemplate">
    {{date}}
    <span style="color: red;">{{errorMsg}}</span> <--- how do i update errorMsg?
</template>

Template.dateTemplate.events({
    'click': function(event, template) {
        template.errorMsg = 'not valid'; <--- this doesn't do anything
    }
});
```

EDIT TO ADDRESS ANSWER BELOW:

```
Template.dateTemplate.events({
    'click': function(event, template) {
        template.errorMsg = function() { return 'not valid';} <--- this also doesn't do anything
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use handlebars for this, because its not something that needs reactivity to pass the message through, reactive variables work best with db data, or data that would be updated by another client over the air.

You could use JQuery (included by default) to update it, it can also get a bit fancier:

```
<template name="dateTemplate">
    {{date}}
    <span style="color: red;display: none" class="errorMessage"></span>
</template>

Template.dateTemplate.events({
    'click': function(event, template) {
        $(template.find('.errorMessage')).html('Your Error Message').slideDown();
    }
});
```

Ive edited it so the error is hidden by default, and slides down with an animation

Comment: Yeah, this is a good solution and it makes sense, I was just really hoping to not have to revert to selecting dom elements with jquery.  One of the amazing things about reactive html, is that your javascript is not tied to the markup at all, and having to bring out jquery selectors breaks that separation.

Comment: The html is tied to the javascript even with handlebars and the templating system. Its just the framework handles this portion of it so they appear seperate. You could use a Session.set if you absolutely  want to use reactive html, you could place it in a subtemplate so the others aren't re-rendered

Comment: Interesting...  How would the subtemplate idea work?  If each instance includes the subtemplate, and I update the subtemplate, wouldn't each instance show the updated subtemplate?  The framework handling the "glue" from my js to the markup is what keeps the two separated.  Meteor's reactive HTML is like the MVVM pattern, except instead of a view model, you're actually able to bind your views directly to the database!  Introducing selectors means changing markup breaks your js and vise-versa...

Comment: Its just putting your error message in another template that only has the {{errorMsg}} and then setting it with Session.set and having a Session.get in that templates helper

Comment: Thanks for the great answers.  I'm gonna work on a smart package to perhaps add the type of functionality I'm looking for...

Answer (score 1):

I'm experimenting handling this by passing a different reactive object to each instance of the template.  Then the template can bind to the reactive object (which is unique per instance) and we don't have any extra boilerplate.

It ends up looking like this:

Initial render:

```
Template.firstTemplateWithPoll(ContextProvider.getContext())
Template.secondTemplateWithPoll(ContextProvider.getContext())
// (I actually pass getContext an identifier so I always get the same context for the same template)
```

JS:

```
Template.poll.events = {
    'click .yes' : function() {
        this.reactive.set('selection', 'yes');
    },

    'click .no' : function() {
        this.reactive.set('selection', 'no');
    }
};

Template.poll.selection = function(arg) {
    return this.reactive.get('selection');
}
```

Template:

```
<template name="poll">
    <blockquote>
        <p>
            Your selection on this poll is {{selection}}
        </p>
    </blockquote>
    <button class='yes'>YES</button>
    <button class='no'>NO</button>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

`template.errorMsg` should be a function that returns your error.

```
Template.dateTemplate.events({
    'click': function(event, template) {
        template.errorMsg = function() { return 'not valid'; };
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried this, and it doesn't do anything.  It has the same effect as just setting that property to a string...